# How to make App communicate with its Finder Sync extension?

Tags: macos-app-extension

CFMessagePortRef class can make finder sync send message to container app, but container app can't send message to finder sync.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far ?

Comment: I just want update my BadgeImage about  file status immediately in finder sync extension ,when container app handle  a  file .  For example, if the file  
has  uploaded to serve success , container app can send a message to finder sync to change badgeImage immediately. The problem is I don't know how to do that . I have  tried to use XPC , CFMessagePort ,it seems that  not work out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should Finder Sync Extension and Main App communicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41016558/how-should-finder-sync-extension-and-main-app-communicate)